# Pygame does not update in Pycharm

Tags: pygame, pycharm

I have set up a venv project in Pycharm and added a Pygame lib. The code runs without showing any errors but the game window object does not display anything.

What could be the issue? Following code should actually display a RED window, but doesn't.

```
import pygame

e = pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

RED = (255,0,0)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(RED)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Screenshot of my Pycharm Project:

[image: Screenshot of my Pycharm Project]

Comment: Try to run the game in the command-line. It should actually work, so we need to figure out if it's a problem with pygame or PyCharm. Also, which operating system and Python version do you use? And check out if `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()` works.

Comment: I have tried flip. no changes. from The IDLE it runs perfectly.